# Selenium Webdriver cannot find element which loads later than DOM

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've been trying to webscrap [this page](https://www.planespotters.net/airlines) using selenium, and as you may notice on the first load a pop-up appears about agreeing on cookies. This pop-up appears around a second later that the rest of the DOM.
The problem is, that even after adding a `sleep` or `WebDriverWait` the driver still cannot click on the Accept button from the pop-up.

Inspecting the page gives that the `Xpath` of the element is `/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/button[1]` so I tried doing it as:

```py
driver.get("https://www.planespotters.net/airlines")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/button[1]').click()
```

with no effect. I get that the element does not exist.

I tried it even with:

```py
driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("#notice > div.message-component.message-row.button-container > button.message-component.message-button.no-children.focusable.primary.sp_choice_type_11").click()')
```

and

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/button[1]'))).click()
```

Any suggestions on how to bypass this pop-up?

Comment: There in no pop-up appearing for me.

Comment: @fam maybe look it up in incognito mode? Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/xdduUuC)

Comment: Your button is in an iframe - you need to switch to it to run selenium against it

Comment: Good job  - just posted an answer for it too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you scroll up on devtools you'll notice your modal window is in an iframe. I queried the 'planespotters' header image (because it's the top item) and you can see it quite clearly:
[image: devtoolsandplanespottsersite]

For selenium switch to your iframe first - this finds the iframe wher the url contains 'privacy':

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'privacy')]")))
```

Then you can complete your action. Be sure to keep that sync in there too.

Then you can switch back to your main window and carry in with your test

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try introducing an implicit wait for your driver. This will happen once per script and will affect all objects. This will wait 10 seconds before throwing an error, or continues whenever it is ready:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still didn't work. I get `Unable to locate element: /html/body/div/div[2]/div[4]/button[1]`